# Firebase: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: firebase

I can't figure out why I recieve "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" on line 16, when I have copied the script strait from firebase.

Here's what I'm working with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>23 Creative</title>

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.0/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
var config = {
apiKey: "XXXXXXX",
authDomain: "XXXXXXXXX",
databaseURL: "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
projectId: "XXXXXXX",
storageBucket: "XXXXXXXXXX",
messagingSenderId: "XXXXXXXXXXXX"
}

firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, 
password).catch(function(,error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  // ...
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add a semi-colon, add it at the end like this:

```
var config = {
    apiKey: "XXXXXXX",
    authDomain: "XXXXXXXXX",
    databaseURL: "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
    projectId: "XXXXXXX",
    storageBucket: "XXXXXXXXXX",
    messagingSenderId: "XXXXXXXXXXXX"
     };
```

Comment: Yep- that was the problem! Thanks!